# cxGrid calculate as you type

Tags: delphi, grid, devexpress, vcl

Simplified I have a cxGrid where I type a start time and a end time. What I need is a function that when I change one of these values calculates the difference and stores this in a third column

I am having trouble finding the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Please elaborate: a DevExpress cxGrid? An underlying database, or just an in-memory structure like TSTringGrid?

Comment: There is a database behind it, but I need the values changed 'on screen'
I have tried the method of changing it in the table, but it isn't shown on the screen before refreshing the data and that has some unwanted effects.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have assigned some sort of Properties editor (probably a DateEdit) to the column.

Given that, you could try to use following code in the OnValidate event of the Properties editor:

```
var
  ValueThirdCol : variant;
  RecordIndex : integer;
begin
  RecordIndex := myView.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex;
  ValueThirdCol := myView.DataController.GetValue(RecordIndex, MyEndDateCol.Index) - myView.DataController.GetValue(RecordIndex, MyStartDateCol.Index);
  myView.DataController.SetValue(RecordIndex, myDifCol.Index, ValueThirdCol);
end;
```

Please note that you might have to tweak this code a bit depending on if you have set GridMode or DataModeController.SyncMode to true, or not, and to use DisplayValue where necessary, but the basic idea should work.

**EDIT**: the OnValidate event of the Properties editor occurs **before** converting the display value to the edit value. That is the reason why this code I provided had to be tweaked.

In order for the code to work, you need to use (for the column being modified) the DisplayValue argument provided by the event instead of the value returned by GetValue.

For example, if the EndDateCol would be the column that triggered the OnValidate, then the code should be

```
ValueThirdCol := DisplayValue - myView.DataController.GetValue(RecordIndex, MyStartDateCol.Index);
```

HTH

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work, but with no luck. It is as it it is using the previous value from the column and the value i type isn't being added to the column (the old value stays there)

Comment: Sorry about the late answer. I'll edit my post to clarify something about the OnValidate event and the DisplayValue.